# Prove $f(x)=1/q \forall x=p/q$ in lowest terms cannot be extended to be continuous on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

Define $f:\mathbb{Q}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=\frac{1}{q}$ where $x = \frac{p}{q}$ in lowest terms.

Want to show there does not exist a function $F$ with domain $\mathbb{R}$ such that 1) $F$ is continuous and 2) $\forall x\in \mathbb{Q}:F(x)=f(x)$

My attempt: Suppose there does exist such a $F$.  Then $\lim_{x\to 1}F(x)=F(1)=1$ since $F$ is continuous.  Hence, $\forall \epsilon >0 \exists \delta>0 \forall x:|x-1|<\delta \implies |F(x)-1|<\epsilon$.  Take $\epsilon = 1/2$.  Then there exists a $\delta >0$ such that $\forall x:|x-1|<\delta \implies 1/2<F(x)<3/2$.  But since the rationals are dense in the reals, there exists a rational number (call it $x_0$) such that $0<|x_0-1|<\delta$.  Since $x_0 \neq 1$, then $F(x_0)\leq1/2$, which contradicts the fact that $1/2<F(x)<3/2$.  Hence no such $F$ exists.

I'm not sure if my solution is fully satisfactory.  Also I was wondering if there are other solutions.  The solution manual stated that such a $F$ would require $F(a)=0 \forall a$ irrational, but I fail to see how this is true.

Comment: Your solution is shorter than the proposed one. The one in the manual consists in looking at an irrational number instead of $1$. If $r_n$ is a sequence of rationals tending to the irrational number $x$, then the denominators of $r_n$ will have to necessarily becomes larger than any prescribed number. Then $f(r_n)\to0$. This forces $F(x)=0$. But then, to finish you would need to look again at a rational point and take limit along the irrationals to get that the values at the rationals would also need to be zero.

Comment: FYI, a roughly similar concept is with [Thomae's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function), which I originally learned as being called the "ruler function".

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy Why is it that the denominators of $r_n$ will become larger?  I am not well-versed in sequences so maybe that is the missing gap in my knowledge, but I'm just curious.

Comment: For any number $M>0$, there are only finitely many denominators $q$ that are smaller than $M$, and finitely many numerators such that $p/q$ is not farther than $1$ from $x$, but there are infinitely many fractions in the sequence $r_n$ if it tends to $x$ (the sequence cannot be eventually constant because $x$ is irrational).

Comment: Am I missing something or can you just look at $f(1/n) = 1/n$ for all positive integers $n$ but $f(0) = 1$ so no extension of $f$ can be continuous at $0$.

Answer (score 1):

For a more simple proof use the characterization of continuity by sequences. Suppose that exists a continuous extension $F$ of $f$, since $\dfrac{n}{n+1}\rightarrow 1$ with $\dfrac{n}{n+1}$ in the lower form for all $n\geq1$, then $\dfrac{1}{n+1}=f(\dfrac{n}{n+1})=F(\dfrac{n}{n+1})\rightarrow F(1)=f(\dfrac{1}{1})=1$ and this is absurd.